# Is it better in longitudinal regression model to have equal number of points per subject?

Tags: regression

Although I dont fully understand why ... apparently in longitudinal regression models, you can have an unequal number of measurements per subject (ex: 3 for subject1, 5 for subject2, etc). I actually posted a question about this where I was told that longitudinal regression can handle unequal number of measurements per subject  [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/627433/why-does-longitudinal-models-work-for-uneven-measurements-per-subject-analysis]... but I did not fully understand why

But in longitudinal regression model, is it better to have an equal number of measurements per subject?(ex: 3 for subject1, 3 for subject2, etc). Will the longitudinal model be expected to work better?

Comment: What exact model do you mean?  Do you mean a multilevel model?  Generalized estimating equations? Repeated measures ANOVA? Or just a regression with time as a covariate?  Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

When using “more exact” methods, I.e., methods that form a full likelihood function (generalized least squares, mixed effects models, Markov models, Bayesian models, etc.) the method properly treats varying number of measurements per subject so the only problem you usually have is that there is loss of efficiency when many subjects have few observations.  Approximate methods such as GEE (generalized estimating equations) and the cluster bootstrap do not have this advantage since they don’t have a full likelihood that respects the interconnections between observations within subject.  They tend to fail with wildly varying cluster sizes, and also with a small number of subjects.  They work best with a large number of subjects with not many records per subject.

Comment: thx! can you please explain "methods that form a full likelihood function ....  properly treats varying number of measurements per subject"?  Is ANOVA an example of incomplete likelihood? What is a full likelihood vs not-full likelihood? (ex: not-full likelihood = approximate methods)?

Comment: why is GEE considered not-full likelihood? isnt GEE used in longitudinal regression .... therefore longitudinal regression requires balanced number of observations per cluster?

Comment: can you please explain " respects the interconnections between observations within subject"?  why doesnt GEE do this? why do these other methods do this?

Comment: "there is loss of efficiency when many subjects have few observations." Does this mean high variance? in general, is it advisable to use longitudinal regression when you only have few measurements per subject because the variance will be very big?

Comment: are there any articles/books that talk about all these problems? i was hoping to take them to my school and have some of the smarter students take a look at them lol... thanks you so much!

Comment: Too many questions, too much work.  What is the most important question for you?

Comment: Thx! I spent the whole night reading ...i think I understand that GEE is not full likelihood because it is not based on probability distribution ... it is a function of the relationship between mean and variance. Since GEE is used in longitudinal regression ... does this mean that longitudinal regression will produce unreliable variance estimates when there are few obs per person?

Comment: Correct.  Said another way, GEE uses an approximately likelihood (e.g., working independence model) that request standard errors to be patched up another way without fixing the underlying likelihood.  GEE is a large-sample approximation and is not robust to missing data, the latter because it doesn’t have the proper repeated measurement connections within a full likelihood.

Comment: I think I understand that rmle/mle can be used for longitudinal mixed effects models ... if response variable is normally distributed. If response is not normal, it is preferable to use GEE because rmle/mle becomes too complicated. So to summarize again - no matter what approach you use ... longitudinal regression with few measurements per medical patients (even if you have many medical patients) will still produce unreliable variance estimates?

Comment: my classmate who can not currently access the internet due to situations back home posted a question (I posted on their behalf) ..... we are a confused as to why GEE can only be used for marginal models and not conditional models. is there any advice you have for us?

Comment: In this context marginal = non-subject-specific, conditional = has subject-specific random effects.  GEE, GLS, and some Markov models are marginal.  Marginal models are entirely appropriate if interested in group-level effects more than subject-level estimates.  Regarding normal distribution there are plenty of full likelihood longitudinal models for non-normal, binary, categorical, or ordinal Y.  See for example [semiparametric Markov models](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov) which are excellent competitors of normal-theory models even if normality holds perfectly.

Comment: thx! just one last time ... longitudinal regression with few measurements per medical patients (even if you have many medical patients) will still produce unreliable variance estimates? its a bad idea?

Comment: No, what matters is the reasons why records exist, e.g., if a patient has more records because he’s sicker and not just at random then results are hard to interpret.  If every patient has only one record the longitudinal dataset reduces to an ordinary univariate analysis that there’s nothing wrong with.  There are some issues with random effects models not working as well if there are only 2-3 observations per patient.